# How to retain a url parameter to the next page

Tags: javascript

I'm new to writing my own javascript, but have successfully used a url parameter to add CSS and a class to my page (thanks to great answers on stackoverflow).  However, next, I need to append the same url parameter to all links on the page, such that if a user clicks on a link, the same parameter goes on to the next page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getQueryVariable(variable){                                          
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
 }

 if (getQueryVariable("code")=="awesome"){
 document.getElementById("copy").style.color="blue";
 document.getElementById("coupon_code").className = "plug_coupon";
 };

 What I need:
 if (getQueryVariable("code")=="awesome"){
   append ?code=awesome to the href  - how to do?
 };

  </script>
```

Thanks!

P.S. Even better would be to append only if the links contain my domain, not if the links are going outside my site (an ad, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Select all your links and then loop through them like this (uses jQuery):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', this.href + myVar);
});
```

If you want to check for only your domain:

```
var comp = new RegExp(location.host);
$('a').each(function() {
    if(comp.test($(this).attr('href'))){
        $(this).attr('href', this.href + myVar);
    }

});
```

Comment: This works well as a standalone, but if I place inside my 'if' statement, as above it doesn't.  Am I missing something on syntax on inserting into the 'if' ? Tx

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jQuery try a while loop:

```
var p = 'myURLParameter';
var i = 0, t; 
while(document.body.getElementsByTagName('a') [i++]) {
  t = this.getAttribute("href");
  this.href = t + "?parameter=" + p;
}
```